# Use of the word "That" twice in a row

Tags: word-usage

Tom believes that that tree bears fruit.  What is it called when two "that's" are used in a row when only one is needed?

Comment: I question your premise that "only one is needed". The pattern is *Tom (believes that) (that tree [i.e the one over there, that one]) (bears fruit)*.

Comment: @Dan The relativiser _that_ is nearly always omissible when it’s not the subject, though, so in the example given, only one of them (the demonstrative determiner) really is needed.

Comment: Yeah, but looking at it as a problem of using two where only one is needed is the wrong way. If you look at constituents (the [bracketed parts] in Dan's comment above), you see that one segment ends with _that_, and the next segment begins with _that_. The two words simply occur next to each other; pure coincidence. If that bothers anybody, they can delete the deletable one -- but it shouldn't bother most people.

Comment: I didn't mean to say that your baby is the problem; I meant to say that that conception is the problem.

Answer (score 3):

> Tom believes that that tree bears fruit. What is it called when two *thats* are used in a row when only one is needed?

It is normal grammar. The first *that* is a conjunction introducing a subordinate clause. The second *that* is a determiner referring to a specific tree.

Compare

*Tom believes that **that** tree bears fruit.*

with

*Tom believes that **this** tree bears fruit.*